# Rigorous book (or other materials) on Circuits, Electronics etc

Tags: electric-circuits, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

What I usually find in a typical book on these topics is the following structure:
"Here is the theorem/fact/formula, here is an example - now go ahead and apply this to some trivial problems that mostly boil down to simply plugging numbers into formulas".

I'm looking for some material that would cover these topics rigorously and in-depth. That is, theorems like Thevenin's or any other aren`t left without a proof, all the physics behind is properly explained(like how Kirchhoff's laws follow from E&M, models such as Drude model will be welcomed...).

Also I would like to see not only some surface-scratching material, but also deep, advanced and difficult situations(sort of olympiad-like problems and examples, where you really have to think, not simply plug in numbers). To be more specific, take AC circuits for example: I'm looking for examples where geometry in vector diagrams(yeah, I want to see them as well, not just jump straight to the complex numbers) isn`t so straightforward due to quite nontrivial circuits, I'd be glad, of course, if the method of complex numbers would be properly covered as well.

All the materials I found so far were about semiconductors: Physics of Semiconductor Devices by Sze and [these](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQms29D1RqeKGBEW8La2a7YuN5_4pSV4k) video lectures, which do skip over some material here and there, but it is typically the material covered in any QM or Analysis course, so overall it is way better than "Look: here's a cool formula and there's a trivial problem to apply it to!" style.

To sum up, I want to find something like Griffiths Electrodynamics but for DC, AC circuits, Network theorems, signal processing, different devices etc. It doesn't have to be one and only book for everything I mentioned, but at least something better than short texts/papers on one particular topic at a time, which is the only thing I could find on lots of theorems, facts and methods from this area.